# Stuck with No connection adapters

Tags: python, python-requests

```
from requests import get
from tabulate import tabulate
# source
with open('source.txt') as fs:
    url_list = fs.readlines()
    url_list = [x.strip() for x in url_list]

for urls in enumerate(url_list):
    response = get(urls)
    status = response.status_code
    print(urls,status)
from requests import get
# destination
with open('destination.txt') as fd:
    url_list = fd.readlines()
    url_list = [x.strip() for x in url_list]

for urls in enumerate(url_list):
    response = get(urls)
    status = response.status_code
    print(urls,status)  
    #print(tabulate(i,urls,status_s,urld,status_d,headers=["sno", "source","status","destination","status"]))
```

(Stuck with No connection adapters were found and )  the output is good`--- like if we give  https://www.google.com  https://www.netflix.com....soon in the list_of_urls.txt file the` output is like-- `

```
without enumarate 
https://www.domain1.com 200
https://www.domain2.com 200
https://www.domain3.com 200
https://www.domain4.com 200
```

with enumarate getting error( No connection adapters were found)
desired output is

```
S.no  Source.                  status     Destination              status
1.    https://www.domain1.com   200      https://www.domain3.com    200
2.    https://www.domain2.com   200      https://www.domain4.com    200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the loops to `for i, urls in enumerate(url_list, 1)` and use `i` variable. For example:

```py
from requests import get

# source
with open("source.txt") as fs:
    url_list = fs.readlines()
    url_list = [x.strip() for x in url_list]

for i, urls in enumerate(url_list, 1):  # <-- note the i, urls
    response = get(urls)
    status = response.status_code
    print(i, urls, status)  # <-- use `i` here

# destination
with open("destination.txt") as fd:
    url_list = fd.readlines()
    url_list = [x.strip() for x in url_list]

for i, urls in enumerate(url_list, 1):  # <-- note the i, urls
    response = get(urls)
    status = response.status_code
    print(i, urls, status)  # <-- use `i` here
```